# How To Show A Count Of Similar Results Generated from *ngFor Loop Angular 6?

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, count

I have a get request which displays an array of objects in the view via  *ngFor loop. I can't seem to figure out how to get the desired result below. This is a really basic example to give you an idea of what I am trying to achieve.

```
data = [
    {
   "name": "Bill",
   "job" : "Builder"
 },
 {
   "name": "John",
   "job":  "Cook"
 },
 {
   "name": "Bill",
   "job" : "Builder"
 }
]
```

Then when the *ngFor loop is created, I'd like to be able to show something like this:

```
Bill [2]
John [1]
```

any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Group your results](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14446511/what-is-the-most-efficient-method-to-groupby-on-a-javascript-array-of-objects) and then use them in your loop:

[Fiddle](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-atyfxh?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new data structure based of your current data, counting the times a name has been visible:

```
data = [
    {
   "name": "Bill",
   "job" : "Builder"
 },
 {
   "name": "John",
   "job":  "Cook"
 },
 {
   "name": "Bill",
   "job" : "Builder"
 }
]

const count = {};
data.forEach(d => {
    count[d.name] = count[d.name] + 1 || 1;
});

console.log(count);
```

output:

```
{ Bill: 2, John: 1 }
```

You should be able to display the names and count from there.